# Creating a function in Laravel where it could calculate and compare the data from 2 different database table

Tags: laravel

I'm quite new on Laravel and currently working on a website where I'm trying to calculate and display lead times and on-target counts for different models. The calculateOnTarget function doesn't seem to be working as expected, and I'm having trouble getting the correct count. The calculateLeadTime function appears to be working fine, but the logic for checking if the lead time is on target doesn't yield the correct count.

[database relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcNMI.png)

dashboard controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTime;
use App\Models\PR;
use App\Models\Production;
use App\Models\Type;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $model = $request->query('model');
        $pr = ($model) ? PR::where('model', $model)->get() : PR::all();
        $prod = ($model) ? Production::where('model', $model) : Production::with('type');
        $prod = $prod->get();

        $totalLeadTimePR = 0;
        $totalLeadTimePP = 0;
        $totalLeadTimeDUT = 0;
        $totalLeadTimePA = 0;
        $totalLeadTimePUT = 0;
        $totalLeadTimeDC = 0;

        // Calculate the sum of calculated lead time for all models
        foreach ($pr as $prItem) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prItem->pr_instruction, $prItem->po_proposal);
            $totalLeadTimePR += $leadTime;
        }

        foreach ($prod as $prodItem) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prodItem->prod_start_principal, $prodItem->prod_finish_principal);
            $totalLeadTimePP += $leadTime;
        }

        foreach ($prod as $prodItem) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prodItem->delivery_start_UT, $prodItem->delivery_finish_UT);
            $totalLeadTimeDUT += $leadTime;
        }

        foreach ($prod as $prodItem) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prodItem->prod_in_stock, $prodItem->assembling_start_by_UT);
            $totalLeadTimePA += $leadTime;
        }

        foreach ($prod as $prodItem) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prodItem->prod_start_UT, $prodItem->prod_finish_UT);
            $totalLeadTimePUT += $leadTime;
        }

        foreach ($prod as $prodItem) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prodItem->delivery_start_cust, $prodItem->delivery_finish_cust);
            $totalLeadTimeDC += $leadTime;
        }

        // Calculate the average lead time
        $averageLeadTimePR = ($pr->count() > 0) ? $totalLeadTimePR / $pr->count() : 0;
        $averageLeadTimePP = ($prod->count() > 0) ? $totalLeadTimePP / $prod->count() : 0;
        $averageLeadTimeDUT = ($prod->count() > 0) ? $totalLeadTimeDUT / $prod->count() : 0;
        $averageLeadTimePA = ($prod->count() > 0) ? $totalLeadTimePA / $prod->count() : 0;
        $averageLeadTimePUT = ($prod->count() > 0) ? $totalLeadTimePUT / $prod->count() : 0;
        $averageLeadTimeDC = ($prod->count() > 0) ? $totalLeadTimeDC / $prod->count() : 0;

        $onTargetPR = $this->calculateOnTargetPR($pr, 'pr_instruction', 'po_proposal', '3');
        $onTargetPP = $this->calculateOnTarget($prod, 'prod_start_principal', 'prod_finish_principal','lt_prod_by_principal');
        $onTargetDUT = $this->calculateOnTarget($prod, 'delivery_start_UT', 'delivery_finish_UT', 'lt_del_to_UT');
        $onTargetPA = $this->calculateOnTarget($prod, 'prod_in_stock', 'assembling_start_by_UT', 'lt_prod_in_stock');
        $onTargetPUT = $this->calculateOnTarget($prod, 'prod_start_UT', 'prod_finish_UT', 'lt_prod_by_UT');
        $onTargetDC = $this->calculateOnTarget($prod, 'delivery_start_cust', 'delivery_finish_cust', 'lt_del_to_cust');

        
        // Other data or calculations for the dashboard
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            // Return JSON data for AJAX requests
            return response()->json([
                'averageLeadTimePR' => $averageLeadTimePR,
                'onTargetPR' => $onTargetPR,
                'prCount' => $pr->count(),
                'prodCount' => $prod->count(),
                'averageLeadTimePP' => $averageLeadTimePP,
                'onTargetPP' => $onTargetPP,
                'averageLeadTimeDUT' => $averageLeadTimeDUT,
                'onTargetDUT' => $onTargetDUT,
                'averageLeadTimePA' => $averageLeadTimePA,
                'onTargetPA' => $onTargetPA,
                'averageLeadTimePUT' => $averageLeadTimePUT,
                'onTargetPUT' => $onTargetPUT,
                'averageLeadTimeDC' => $averageLeadTimeDC,
                'onTargetDC' => $onTargetDC,
            ]);
        }

        return view('index', ['averageLeadTimePR' => $averageLeadTimePR, 'averageLeadTimePP' => $averageLeadTimePP,
        'averageLeadTimeDUT' => $averageLeadTimeDUT, 'averageLeadTimePA' => $averageLeadTimePA, 'averageLeadTimePUT' => $averageLeadTimePUT,
        'averageLeadTimeDC' => $averageLeadTimeDC, 'onTargetPR' => $onTargetPR,
        'onTargetPP' => $onTargetPP,
        'onTargetDUT' => $onTargetDUT,
        'onTargetPA' => $onTargetPA,
        'onTargetPUT' => $onTargetPUT,
        'onTargetDC' => $onTargetDC, 
        'pr' => $pr,
        'prod' => $prod,
        'model' => $model]);
    }

    private function calculateLeadTime($startDate, $endDate)
    {
            $startDate = new DateTime($startDate);
            $endDate = new DateTime($endDate);

            $leadTime = $endDate->diff($startDate);

            return $leadTime->days;
    }

    private function calculateOnTargetPR($items, $startColumn, $endColumn, $targetLeadTime)
    {
        $onTargetCount = 0;

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($item->$startColumn, $item->$endColumn);

            if ($leadTime <= $targetLeadTime) {
                $onTargetCount++;
            }
        }

        return $onTargetCount;
    }

    private function calculateOnTarget($prod, $startColumn, $endColumn, $ltColumn)
{
    $onTargetCount = 0;

    foreach ($prod as $prodItem) {
        $type = $prodItem->type;

        if ($type instanceof Type) {
            // Determine the target lead time based on the type and LTs columns
            $targetLeadTime = $this->getTargetLeadTime($type, $ltColumn);
            // Calculate the lead time for the Production model
            $leadTime = $this->calculateLeadTime($prodItem->$startColumn, $prodItem->$endColumn);

            // Check if the lead time is on target
            if ($leadTime <= $targetLeadTime) {
                    $onTargetCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $onTargetCount;
}

    // Function to fetch the target lead time from the Type model based on LTs column
    private function getTargetLeadTime($type, $ltColumn)
    {
        // Adjust the column name as per your database
        return optional($type)->$ltColumn;
    }

}
```

My intention was, the $ltColumn would fetch the data from Type table. Then, the code would compare it with Lead Time calculation from Production table.

However, the current code can't give me the correct output. For some reason, it couldn't calculate the target lead time. With the current data, it should give me this output for KCMB and KCMS model:
On Target : 1
Over 0 :

But it given me this output :
On Target : 0
Over : 1

which means it can only calculate how many data for the selected model in the database and can't detect which model have the same LT or below the standard and which model is over the LT standard.

I can't figure out where's the problem so I hope anyone could please help me.

dashboard view :
[dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW203.png)

this is how I called the function in blade.view

```
          <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-xl-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">
                <h6 class="mb-3 mt-2 text-capitalize">Delivery to UT</h6>
                <div class="card shadow-primary mx-auto d-inline-block" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                  <div class="card-header mb-0">
                    <h5 id="averageLeadTimeDUT" class="mb-0 mt-0 text-capitalize">{{ intval($averageLeadTimeDUT) }}</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="average-value" style="margin-top: -15px;">
                      <p class="mt-0">days</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer p-3 ">
                <p id="onTargetDUT" class="mb-0 mt-0" style="margin-top: 10px;">On Target: {{ $onTargetDUT }}</p>
                <p id="overDUT" class="mb-0" style="margin-top: 10px;">Over : {{ strval($prod->count())-$onTargetDUT }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: if($type instanceof Type){...} what is the objective of this comparison? Because the way it is currently it just checks for the existence of the type relationship on the $prodItem

Comment: If $type is an instance of the Type class or any of its subclasses, the code inside the if block will be executed.
If $type is not an instance of the Type class or its subclasses, the code inside the if block will be skipped.

Comment: Please consider reducing your code to the relevant bits and explain what you would expect and what you get instead